# Section 4.2 in Loring Tu's Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections

Section 4.2 in Loring Tu's *Differential Geometry*:

[image]

**My Question:** Since $D_XY −D_YX = [X,Y]$, then why define the quantity $T(X,Y)=D_XY −D_YX - [X,Y]$? Isn't $T$ always equal to $0$? I got very confused, and I want to know whether I have got anything wrong.

Comment: The wording is unfortunate. In general we are interested in derivative $D$ **different** from the directional derivative. In that case the torsion might be non-zero.

Comment: I think you might like the answers to a similar-in-spirit question over on MathOverflow, in particular Tom Boardman's answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20493/what-is-torsion-in-differential-geometry-intuitively

Comment: @ArcticChar what's unfortunate with the wording? If $[X,Y]$ is defined as the Lie bracket in '(A.2)', then $T(X,Y)=0$. If $[X,Y]$ is not defined as the Lie bracket in '(A.2)', then we might not have $T(X,Y)=0$. Am I wrong? I posted answer

Comment: @SammyBlack What's the relevance? That question is asking for intuition on torsion. This question is asking how we don't always have $T=0$. I think it's pretty easy/simple/shallow based on an oversight: If $[X,Y]$ is defined as the Lie bracket in '(A.2)', then $T(X,Y)=0$. If $[X,Y]$ is not defined as the Lie bracket in '(A.2)', then we might not have $T(X,Y)=0$. Am I wrong? Or is there some hard/complicated/deep thing that I missed? (Note: 'easy' here is not meant as an attack against the OP. It's meant to wonder why 2 commenters here are talking as if there's some deeper meaning or something)

Comment: @ArcticChar oh wait never mind. you're right.  forgot this book already apparently. Lol hehe. I got confused with the $D$ vs $\nabla$ and the lie bracket thing. I thought it was that $[,]$ means something else later on. Actually it's that $D$ means something else later on in the sense that $D$ is generalised to $\nabla$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're completely correct. This is a slightly unfortunate sentence. Later in the book, Tu will introduce the more general notion of an affine connection $\nabla$ on $TM$. This is a gadget quite similar to $D$, in that it is a map $\nabla:\mathfrak{X}(M)\times \mathfrak{X}(M)\to \mathfrak{X}(M)$ which is written $\nabla(X,Y)=\nabla_X Y$ and "differentiates" $Y$ with respect to $X$.

It satisfies moreover the properties of being $C^\infty(M)$ linear in $X$ and $\Bbb{R}-$linear in $Y$. The point of saying all of this is that for a general affine connection $\nabla$, we define the quantity $T(X,Y)=\nabla_X Y-\nabla_Y X-[X,Y]$ to be the torsion of $\nabla$, which is a tensor that eats a pair of vector fields and returns a vector field.

The reason we want to introduce this terminology is that a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ has a unique torsion free connection $\nabla$ compatible with the metric $g$. Compatibility here means that for all $X,Y,Z\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, we have
$$
X g(Y,Z)=g(\nabla_XY,Z)+g(Y,\nabla_X Z)\:\:\:\:\text{(a version of the product rule)}.
$$
We call this the *Levi-Civita connection* and it shows us that a Riemannian manifold comes for free with a "canonical" choice of connection. This is in turn useful, because it gives us a notion of parallel transport of vector fields. Given a parametrized curve $\gamma:I\to M$, we say that a vector field $V$ along $\gamma$ is *parallel* with respect to $\nabla$ if
$$
\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}V=0\:\:\:\text{(parallel transport equation)}.
$$
If you look here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20493/what-is-torsion-in-differential-geometry-intuitively at Anonymous's answer, they provide an example of a connection on $\Bbb{R}^3$ which is *not* the Levi-Civita connection (because it has nonzero torsion) and with respect to which the parallel translation rotates a vector as it "moves" along a curve. This perhaps explains the reason why it is called torsion. $T(X,Y)\equiv 0$ means (roughly) that there is no twisting in the translation in some sense.

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4122052/1)**:   Arctic Char is right. I forgot this book already apparently. Lol hehe. I got confused with the $D$ vs $\nabla$ and the lie bracket thing. I thought it was that $[,]$ means something else later on. Actually it's that $D$ means something else later on in the sense that $D$ is generalised to $\nabla$.

For $T_\nabla(X,Y) := \nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X- [X,Y]$, we have $T_\nabla(X,Y)=0$ for $\nabla=D$ because of the way the Lie bracket is defined. Actually the way the Lie bracket is defined gives us

$T_\nabla(X,Y) := \nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X- (D_XY - D_YX)$

---

**Edit 2**: Wait I think it need not be Lie bracket in general. This book often refers to Tu's other book An Introduction to Manifolds. In Section 14, we have brackets

> [image]

It's not explicitly mentioned, but I think we can apply for $\mathfrak X(M)$ the zero bracket. But yeah it's probably just the $D$ vs $\nabla$ thing. if it's lie bracket, then check if $\nabla = D$. if it's not lie bracket, then depends on what the bracket is.

Comment: I think it's more what ArcticChar was saying in the comments: in my experience, when talking about vector fields $[X,Y]$ *always* indicates the usual Lie bracket.  On the other hand, we often consider different notions of derivative (for example, the Levi-Civita connection associated to a Riemannian metric), and these can possibly lead to non-zero $T$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following your second sentence.  You're saying that in Tu's book, he eventually uses the notation $[X,Y]$ for vector fields to mean something other than the Lie brakcet?

Comment: @JasonDeVito ok i checked the book again. I think I was mixing up $D$ and $\nabla$ vs the lie bracket thing. no need to apologise. thanks! editing answer now.

Comment: @JasonDeVito wait. please see my 2nd edit. i think we can do like $[X,Y]=0$ ? i mean, is the zero bracket a lie bracket?

Comment: There are certainly common situations where the notation $[X,Y]$ can refer to things other than Lie bracket of vector fields.  This most prominently occurs in the study of Lie algebras, where $X$ and $Y$ need not be vector fields at all (just vectors in some random vector space).  The claim I am making is that, in my own experience, when $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields on a manifold, the notation $[X,Y]$ has always meant the usual Lie bracket of vector fields.

Comment: @JasonDeVito right right thanks. it's probably the $D$ vs $\nabla$ thing lol. i did check the references carefully to see if the objects weren't vector fields and saw like oh ok i guess it's just lie bracket, but then i also thought like $[,]$ could be zero bracket, even though it's not explicitly mentioned